# How do I know what type of wood I'm buying?

Tags: wood, woodworking

I am new to woodworking, and I'm working on a small project requiring some 2x4s.

I want to buy [this one](http://www.homedepot.com/p/2-in-x-3-in-x-96-in-Premium-Whitewood-Stud-845000/202059590) from Home Depot. Is this solid wood or engineered wood?  They didn't say anything in their description. How can I find out?

Comment: Is this an indoor or outdoor project? Will the wood be in contact with damp surfaces?

Comment: @bib indoor proj. gonna build a bed for kid.

Comment: Be sure to avoid pressure treated wood. It has chemicals that protect against rot and insects, but is not good for skin contact, especially by children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"White wood" is a generic term for whatever fast-growing wood is cheapest at that time and in that place. It may be pine, fir, or occasionally even poplar (which is as fast-growing and soft as most "softwoods" despute being considered a hardwood). It will be a solid wood, though there may be cases where boards have been spliced to get useful sizes.

Answer (score 3):

From the picture you can tell that it is solid wood because you can see the annual rings, and they are continuous over the whole width of the stud, so nothing is glued together.